# Calling Class from another File ASP.NET VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, import

Lets say I have a class like this in class1.vb:

```
Public Class my_class
  Public Sub my_sub()
   Dim myvar as String
   myvar = 10
   Session("myvar") = myvar
  End Sub
End Class
```

Then I have a ASP.NET page with a code-behind file, default.aspx and default.aspx.vb and I want to call my_class. I'm doing the following, but it doesn't work:

```
Imports my_app.my_class
Partial Public Class _default
   Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   my_class()
 End Sub
End Class
```

I get a "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Imports my_app.my_class
Partial Public Class _default
   Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
       Dim myClass as new my_class()
    myClass.my_sub()
 End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: does your new code look like the above (recently edited) code?

Answer (score 3):

Try importing the namespace that contains the class, not the class itself.

So instead of this:

```
Imports my_app.my_class
```

do this:

```
Imports my_app
```

VB.NET imports namespaces into the file scope to help the compiler resolve type names that aren't fully qualified.  This means you are free to use all types declared in the `my_app` namespace in this code file without prefixing the type name with `my_app`.

Okay, once you have done that you will need to do switch up the contents of `Page_Load` to create an instance of `my_class` like this:

```
Dim foo As New my_class
my_class.my_sub()
```

Now you have an instance of `my_class` called `foo` and you can call instance methods on it.

The other thing you could do is make `my_sub` a `Shared` method so you don't have to create an instance:

```
Public Shared Sub my_sub()
```

If you do this then you do not need to create an instance of `my_class` to call `my_sub` - you can call `my_sub` directly:

```
my_class.my_sub()
```

Comment: That gets rid of the reference to a non-shared member error but replaces it with:
'GetUserInfo' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: I think you may have to post some more code - I don't see that method declared anywhere in your original post.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. Same error, just remove the 'GetUserInfo' and replace with 'my_sub'

Comment: Oh ok, no worries! I have updated my answer to show what else needs to happen.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I wish I could give two answers the green checkmark...but I gave it to Derek, b/c I received his answer first. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to call  my_sub() on my_class?  You can either mark it as a shared methog so that it can be called as `my_class.my_sub()`

or

instantiate an instance of it:

```
Dim myclass as new my_class()
myclass.my_sub()
```

Comment: See Derek's response below and my comments - throws an error.